# Cannot get the width of div

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<tr>
  <td style = "padding-left: 2%; padding-right: 2%;">
    <span style="padding: 3px; float: left; margin-right:13px;">RISK TAKER</span>
    <div id = "risktakertotal" style= "margin: auto;" class="progress">
      <div id = "risktaker" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="color:black; width:0%; background-color: #0097a7;"></div>
      <div class="vertical-line" id = "risktakerAvg" style=""></div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td id = "risktakerKB" ><h4></h4></td> 
  <td id = "risktakerS"><h4></h4></td>
</tr>
```

I have a very simple table with a Bootstrap progress bar in it. I have a vertical line that indicates the average for the bar (not the actual progress). To calculate where to put that line, I want to get the total width of "risktakertotal" and set the lines margin-left to a percentage of that total width.

However, using Javascript, I cannot get the width of that div. I've used .width(), .style.width, .offsetWidth and anything else I could find online to no luck. Does anyone know of I way I can do this? Or another way that I can move this vertical line without the total width?

EDIT:

```
var riskTakerQuestions = data['risk taker'] ? data['risk taker'] : 0;
var riskTakerPercent = Math.round(riskTakerQuestions/11 * 100);
if(riskTakerPercent > 75) {
    riskTakerPercent = 100
    document.getElementById('risktaker').innerHTML = "Score exceeds 75%";
}
else{
    document.getElementById('risktaker').innerHTML = riskTakerPercent + "%";
    riskTakerPercent = riskTakerPercent / .75
}
document.getElementById('risktaker').style.width = riskTakerPercent + "%";
document.getElementById('risktaker').setAttribute("aria-valuenow", riskTakerPercent + "%");

var riskTakerAvg = 54;
if (riskTakerAvg > 75) {
    riskTakerAvg = 100;  
}
else {
    riskTakerAvg = riskTakerAvg / .75;
}
alert($('#risktakertotal').width());
alert(document.getElementById("risktakertotal").offsetWidth)
```

here is my javascript for everyone wondering. Everything returns 0 (this is the progress class from bootstrap). The other option I have it to get the width of "#risktaker" in pixels. In my javascript, however, I set the element in terms of percent, so any function I use returns the width of "#risktaker" in percent.

Comment: What do you get when you try those various methods?

Comment: 0 is what is returned

Comment: Any chance you have a CSS rule on `.progress` that says `width:0;`?

Comment: Toss a border around the div and see what it looks like. *is* it really 0?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this yet?

```
document.getElementById("risktakertotal").offsetWidth
```

If I am wrong someone please do correct me

I'd say wait till someone verify's I am right before trying it.

Comment: Yup! No luck there either :(. I edited the main question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

You must have an error elsewhere, because the following works just fine.

```
$('#risktakertotal').width();
```

You can see in this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MeJxmx.

Comment: still 0. I'm not sure if the codepen uses bootstrap. Check the latest edit.

Comment: @ShyamKotak What is this: data['risk taker']?

Answer (score 0):

[image]Hi please refere this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/fyByiAP9qc7Rb0CdlIGe?p=preview

```
// Add your javascript here
$(function(){
 console.log($('#risktakertotal').width())
});
```

check the jquery u included or not  check the screenshot

Comment: I included the jquery in the main question in an edit

Comment: did u check my plunker console got the width @ShyamKotak

Comment: is that using bootstrap? I ran the code and I am still getting 0

Comment: check the library included , then how come i got the console check the screen shot @ShyamKotak